# return Anonymous type from compiled query delegate

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I want to return an anonymous type from a compiled query, which selects multiple columns from two tables.

I tried using:

```
public static Func < DBEntities, string>
```

but not able to compile it. I tried creating a new datatype **BOMWorkOrder** but could not make it work. May be ia m missing some syntax.

```
public static Func<DBEntities, string, IQueryable<BOMWorkOrder>> compiledWorkorderQuery =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((DBEntities ctx, string bomNumber) =>
            from items in ctx.BM10200 
            from orders in ctx.BM10300
            where orders.Parent_Component_ID == -1 &&
                    orders.ITEMNMBR == bomNumber &&
                    orders.TRX_ID == items.TRX_ID
            select new 
            {  bomWorkOrder =
                items.TRXDATE,
                orders.TRX_ID,
                orders.ITEMNMBR,
                orders.Assemble_Quantity
            });
```

where work order will be:

```
public class BOMWorkOrder
{
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public int AssemblyQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've created the type `BOMWorkOrder`, use that type rather than an anonymous type:

```
... select new BOMWorkOrder 
    { 
        TransactionDate = items.TRXDATE,
        TransactionId = orders.TRX_ID,
        ItemNumber = orders.ITEMNMBR,
        AssemblyQuantity = orders.Assemble_Quantity
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return a list of anonymous objects, you will not be able to access the properties ( unless you use `dynamic` )

You're just missing the type name in your `select`:

```
...
select new BOMWorkOrder
{
    TransactionData = items.TRXDATE,
    TransactionId = orders.TRX_ID,
    ItemNumber = orders.ITEMNBBR,
    AssemblyQuantity = orders.Assemble_Queantity,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select new bomWorkOrder
    {  
        TransactionDate =items.TRXDATE,
        TransactionId =orders.TRX_ID,
        ItemNumber =orders.ITEMNMBR,
        AssemblyQuantity =orders.Assemble_Quantity
    });
```